# How to remove com.google.android.maps from a Xamarin project

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

I developed a Xamarin Android app several years ago.  This app uses an Android Maps V1 api.

I'm trying to port the application to the latest Xamarin in VS 2015.  As part of that I need to update the V1 Maps api to now use Android Maps V2 (via Google Play Services).

The issue I am facing is that there seems to be left over references to the V1 libraries.  When I compile the app I get several Errors, key among them being:

> error: package com.google.android.maps does not exist

When I double-click the error it opens a file `<project>\obj\Debug\android\src\mono\com\google\android\maps\ItemizedOverly_OnFocusChangeListenerImplementor.java`.

As far as I can tell `ItemizedOverlay` is no longer a Maps V2 class.  So this leads me to believe its a left over reference to a Maps V1 class.

Any thoughts on how to remove these left over references?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

Delete the `<project>\obj` directory and recompile.